# asp.net mvc 5 page show/hide/access based on table value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Please see code below that creates menu items. Now how can I show/hide/access a menu item that is created as below. Also I want to make sure user do not directly access page. I want to do this based on value in one my table( no default table). I know we can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` based on roles, but like I mentioned I want to manually look for a value in a custom table then show/hide/allow access of page.

Thanks.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "Index", "AspNetRoles", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })  </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "AspNetUsers", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Groups", "Index", "UserGroupRoles", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

Note: After getting help from Stephen ,I managed to write below code. But now I am getting error

> "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."

Controller Code

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using .Models;

namespace TestProj.Controllers
{
    public class NavigationVMController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Navigation()
        {
            NavigationVM NavItems = new NavigationVM();
            NavItems.CanViewRoles = true; //setting all true temporarily for testing
            NavItems.CanViewUsers = true;
            NavItems.CanViewUserGroups = true;

            //return View(Alex);
            return View("_Navigation", NavItems);
        }
        // GET: NavigationVM
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model Code

```
namespace TestProj.Models
{
    public class NavigationVM 
    {
        public bool CanViewRoles { get; set; }
        public bool CanViewUsers { get; set; }
        public bool CanViewUserGroups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial view Code

```
@model TestProj.Models.NavigationVM

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @if (Model.CanViewRoles)
         {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "Index", "AspNetRoles", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })  </li>
        }
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "AspNetUsers", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Groups", "Index", "UserGroupRoles", new { }, new { @style = "color:#21ce99;" })</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

Calling code from _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("Navigation", "NavigationVMController")
```

Comment: The easiest thing you can do is do your check as the first step in each `Index` action; You might also want to look into filtering: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs. For users not directly accessing a page, you can look into the [childActionOnly attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: I am really very new to asp.net so will look into your links. Meanwhile can I get value from table in view. Then use the value to make decisions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a partial view for the navigation links and call a `ChildActionOnly` method that initializes a view model based on some parameters that you can use to conditionally check which links should be displayed

View model

```
public class NavigationVM
{
  public bool CanViewRoles { get; set; }
  public bool CanViewUsers { get; set; }
  public bool CanViewUserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (probably in a BaseController so its available everywhere

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Navigation
{
  NavigationVM model = new NavigationVM();
  model.canViewRoles = ?? // call a service which returns the value based on the current user
  ....
  return PartialView("_Navigation", model)
}
```

Partial View (_Navigation.cshtml)

```
@model yourAssembly.NavigationVM
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  @if (Model.CanViewRoles)
  {
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "Index", "AspNetRoles", new { }, new { @style = "color:#333;" })</li>
  }
  .... // ditto for CanViewUsers and CanViewUserGroups
  </ul>
</div>
```

and in the main view or layout

```
@Html.Action("Navigation") // renders the navigation links
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

This will only display the appropriate links, but of course a user could still type in the address to try and access the pages so your controller methods still need to perform validation

AspNetRolesController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // Check permissions based on user
  bool canView = ?? // call a service which returns the value based on the current user
  if (!canView)
  {
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for detailed reply. Lot to learn here :) Hope I don't have followup question :)

Comment: Looks like I am stuck at creating controller. I am not using any base controller. In this case what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `BaseController` although you should have one (and then every controller inherits from `BaseController` rather than `Controller`. That way you can have common code in one place rather than duplicating code. If you don't want a `BaseController` then just create a new controller (say) `MenuController` and add the `public ActionResult Navigation()` method to it, then in the view or layout, call it using `@Html.Action("Navigation", "Menu")`

Comment: Stephen, will it possible to have a simple project created with what you suggested. I am very new to all this and I keep getting one or other error. Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Which piece of the code are you not understanding?

Comment: Error says "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. Where and when does the error occur? What are your routes. It would probably be best to either ask a new question or edit this one with the code you have tried and detail of the error

Comment: You have deleted the original code block and not the question makes no sense - you need to edit that back in

Comment: For a start it needs to be `@Html.Action("Navigation", "NavigationVM")` (not `"NavigationVMController"`). And in the partial you need to wrap the 2nd and 3rd links inside `if` blocks also

Comment: i corrected the controller name. I was just testing one link for now. But now I am getting major error. IIS is crashing and it says "IIS Express worker process has stopped working". I restarted the system and still IIS is crashing. And if I comment the  `@Html.Action` code IIS is not crashing.

Comment: In the `public ActionResult Navigation()` method, it should be `return PartialView("_Navigation", NavItems);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76595/discussion-between-ary-and-stephen-muecke).